# How to register user exit of UIWebView

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, uiwebview

When logging in through Facebook a webview is presented in-app to a user. If the connection is very slow it's possible that the user will press "Done" on the webview. This presents an issue with activity indicators and invalidating timers for bad connections. How can you register that a user closed out of an in-app webview?

You could do it in `viewDidAppear`, and just reset everything. But that poses it's own problems. What's the correct way?

```
  PFFacebookUtils.logInInBackgroundWithReadPermissions(permissions) {
        (user: PFUser?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
```

[image]

Comment: Show some code. How you are presenting the Facebook login screen would be a good start.

Comment: Code added and screen shot added. Since I don't present the UIWebView myself I don't know how to access it.

Comment: Wouldn't the block passed into the Parse SDK method indicate that the login is complete and that the view is or will return to your view?

Comment: If the page loads and the cancel button is pressed, yes. But not if the actual webview is closed out of by pressing done, even if the page does load. That returns nothing out of the block. So far I can't find a handle for it.